# AWS S3 Java SDK times out when attempting a PutObject request

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

I have some code that attempts to upload images to an s3 bucket. All of them are around 100-200kb.

However, after a few attempts uploads I always get the following stacktrace:

> com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request:
>   Timeout waiting for connection from pool  at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:713)
>   at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:453)
>   at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:415)
>   at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:364)
>   at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3964)
>   at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1538)

If I do GetObject on my code, I do not get that problem, only on uploads.

Code is the following:

```
public PutObjectResult uploadImage(String key, InputStream inputStream, ObjectMetadata metadata) {
        Optional<String> bucketName = propertyResolver.instance().value("s3.bucket.url");
        String resourcePath = BASE_PATH + key;

        PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName.get(), resourcePath, inputStream, metadata);
        PutObjectResult result;
        try {
            result = s3Client.putObject(request);
        } catch (AmazonClientException amazonClientException) {
            amazonClientException.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

I've attempted to find a solution online but all I could find were issues regarding the GetObject and not consuming the response properly.

Comment: we just started seeing this error occur intermittently. as of this moment, we are able to execute putObject similarity to your code above.

Comment: btw, what version of AWS SDK are you using?

Comment: How many concurrent calls are you making to `uploadImage`? The call to `putObject` itself is a blocking call but if you're making hundreds/thousands at once across many threads there may be some contention in the connection pool. The error seems to suggest this. How are you configuring the S3 client? What version of the SDK are you using?